# R random forest feature selection based on AUC

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection

For binary option prediction (rise, fall) I am trying random forest in R but the importance measures and OOB are biased in my case

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289011/auc-base-features-importance-using-random-forest) but it is Python related.

Is there an R package approach for automatic feature selection that

- is based on AUC
- maybe allows me to define my own evaluation function (money earned is function of recall and precision rates)
- maybe allows me to specify the cross-validation approach: randomly selecting traing and test case is biased, as there are timeseries data, where test data must be later than training data

Comment: Have you looked at [caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/)?  It is pretty much the package for model tuning.

Comment: I use zoo for rolling. AUC for guess what and a lot of my own code. I read this function exist in caret package, filterVarImp()
It is not easy to perform variable selection though as your model error would quite high al ready

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this question, I found this package that might help you:

i. It's called AUCRF, it performs feature selection in a random forest model based on optimizing AUC. 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AUCRF/AUCRF.pdf

ii. It does allow cross-validation of your AUC based selection
    AUCRFcv(x, nCV = 5, M = 20)

where nCV is number of folds, M = number of repeats.

iii. Regarding allowing your own evaluation, it does have an option where you can specify the formula using ~ but you will have to explore that more for your specific case, since you have not provided test code.

Hope this helps!